# Copy contents of one node to another XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

Using XLST 1.0 I want to copy any nodes called INSTRUCTIONS, and the child elements, to another location in the tree.

There can be more than one INSTRUCTIONS containers under WO.

```
/my:TRANS/my:DE/my:CO/my:RE/my:PR/my:WO
```

The target location of the INSTRUCTIONS is under PRSI and PRSI does not exist in the original source.

```
/my:TRANS/my:DE/my:CO/my:RE/my:PR/my:PRSI
```

Please advise.

Here is some example input. I'm omitting the namespace:

```
<trans>
<de>
<co>
<re>
<pr>
<wo>
<INSTRUCTIONS>
<category>1</category>
<description>abc</description>
</INSTRUCTIONS>
<INSTRUCTIONS>
<category>2</category>
<description>xyz</description>
</INSTRUCTIONS>
</wo>
</pr>
</re>
</co>
</de>
</trans>
```

Here is expected output. I'm omitting the namespace:

```
<trans>
<de>
<co>
<re>
<pr>
<PRSI>
<INSTRUCTIONS>
<category>1</category>
<description>abc</description>
</INSTRUCTIONS>
<INSTRUCTIONS>
<category>2</category>
<description>xyz</description>
</INSTRUCTIONS>
</PRSI>
</pr>
</re>
</co>
</de>
</trans>
```

This is what I have so far.

```
  <xsl:template match="//my:TRANS/my:DE/my:CO/my:RE/my:PR/my:WO">
    <my:PRSI>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
     </xsl:copy>
    </my:PRSI>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, but complete example of the input and the expected result of transforming it - see: [mcve]. Also post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: I edited my original question with inputs and expected output.

Comment: To me this looks like you just want to rename `wo` to `PRSI` - which is a trivial task. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes this is true, but in the future other child elements may be in the WO container in the source, which I actually do not want in PRSI

Comment: Then what do you want to happen to them?

Comment: Every child element of WO not named INSTRUCTIONS I want to disappear, then rename WO TO PRSI.

Comment: OK, so where exactly are you stuck with this? Start with the *identity transform* template, add a template matching `wo`, rename it and apply templates to `INSTRUCTIONS` only. It should take 5 minutes, assuming you have spent an hour with a basic XSLT tutorial.

Comment: Sorry not sure exactly how to get it done. Could use your wisdom. I posted something above.